# VSTS Remote Powershell task throwing error

Tags: windows, powershell, azure-devops, powershell-remoting, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am creating a build definition in VSTS which will build windows services and deploy windows services to a particular server.

I am able to copy all required windows services files into the server. I am using a powershell script to install and start these windows services. I have powershell script already in the server. My last VSTS task  Remote Powershell task is throwing the following

> [error]Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message : WinRM cannot complete the operation. Verify that the specified computer name is valid, that the computer is accessible over the network, and that a firewall exception for the WinRM service is enabled and allows access from this computer. By default, the WinRM firewall exception for public profiles limits access to remote computers within the same local subnet. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

Powershel Script Code:

```
$serviceName = "Service"
$displayName = "Service name"            
$sourceLocation = "C:\temp\Service\bin\Release\*"
$destinationLocation = "C:\TestService\"
$binaryName = $destinationLocation + "Service1.exe"
$serviceName = "Service1"
$serviceDef = Get-Service -Name $serviceName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

If ($serviceDef -eq $null)
{
   New-Item $destinationLocation -ItemType directory 
   Copy-Item $sourceLocation $destinationLocation -Force
   New-Service -Name $serviceName -StartupType Automatic -DisplayName $displayName -BinaryPathName $binaryName
}
else
{
  # has already been installed
  if($serviceDef.Status -eq "Running")
  {
    Stop-Service -Name $serviceName        
  }
  Copy-Item $sourceLocation $destinationLocation -Force
}
Start-Service -Name $serviceName


$serviceName = "Service2"
$displayName = "Service2"            
$sourceLocation = "C:\temp\Service2\bin\Release\*"
$destinationLocation = "C:\Service2\"
$binaryName = $destinationLocation + "Service2.exe"
$serviceName = "Service2"
$serviceDef = Get-Service -Name $serviceName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

If ($serviceDef -eq $null)
{
   New-Item $destinationLocation -ItemType directory 
   Copy-Item $sourceLocation $destinationLocation -Force
   New-Service -Name $serviceName -StartupType Automatic -DisplayName $displayName -BinaryPathName $binaryName
}
else
{
  # has already been installed
  if($serviceDef.Status -eq "Running")
  {
    Stop-Service -Name $serviceName        
  }
  Copy-Item $sourceLocation $destinationLocation -Force
}
Start-Service -Name $serviceName
```

Comment: Did you enable windows remoting on the destination computer (`Enable-PSRemoting` or `winrm quickconfig`) ?

Comment: This is not a problem with the script. It's a problem with WinRM / PowerShell remoting.

Comment: Did you use Hosted Agent to run the build? Can the remote machine be accessed from public internet?

Comment: I am using self hosted agent. I pinged the server where i am trying to run poweshell script from the build server i.e. server where i hosted a build agent

Comment: The ping was successful

Comment: @EddieChen-MSFT, The remote machine can be access from public internet only through VPN as this machine belongs to an organization

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, it should be the WinRM issue, you need to enable WinRM on the particular server.

Just try to run command `winrm quickconfig` from cmd as a administrator on the particular server to enable WinRM. After that try it again.

```
 C:\Windows\system32>WinRM quickconfig
 WinRM service is already running on this machine.
 WinRM is not set up to allow remote access to this machine for management.
 The following changes must be made:

 Create a WinRM listener on HTTP://* to accept WS-Man requests to any IP on this
 machine.

 Make these changes [y/n]? y

 WinRM has been updated for remote management.

 Created a WinRM listener on HTTP://* to accept WS-Man requests to any IP on this
 machine.
```

Comment: i tried the command and it says that "WinRM service is already running on this machine", "WinRM is already set up for remote management on this computer."

Comment: Whenever i try to run the build definition, one thing i notice is that  VSTS RemotePowershell task runs on port 5986, so you think this can be the problem?

Comment: Along with adding an exception on the VM's firewall, if you are hosting in Azure, go to the "Networking" Settings and add a firewall exception there as well.